# Send a SOAP request to another API?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, soap

I'm trying to figure out hot to send a SOAP request from a Spring Boot rest api to another api and retrieve XML data, but I can't figure out how. The only thing I'm finding is how to create a service to retrieve XML data from. I've only worked with JSON APIs before. Anyone with any good source I can check out..?

Comment: SOAP is XML so your question doesn't really make sense...

Comment: What would be the right question then...? As far as I know something like a RestTemplate only works with JSON, correct? And SOAP is a protocol, isn't it? I need to send a soap request from a spring boot api to another api and retrieve XML data.

Comment: Whilst SOAp is a protocol it is XML, your understanding of RestTemplate is also wrong. I strongly suggest to do some reading/studying on the technologies you are using instead of working with false/wrong understandings.

Comment: Ok. Could you provide me some links where I can read up on it?